# Storing/Getting the name and email address of the user in a variable who submitted the comment

Tags: 2011, content-delivery, ugc

```
<ugc:ForEachComment runat="server">
<ugc:ContextVariable runat="server" Var="ugcComment.user.name"/>
</ugc:ForEachComment>
```

By this I can print the name of the user who submitted the comment but now I want to store the name of the user in a variable in aspx page. How can I achive this?

I have tried creating the object of Comment class inside foreach comment but it gives the null reference error.

```
<ugc:ForEachComment runat="server">
<% Comment comment = new Comment();  %>         
   <%=  comment.User.Name; %>
</ugc:ForEachComment>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While in a UGC ForEach loop you can use `HttpContext.Current.Items` to get the current rendered comment like this:

```
HttpContext.Current.Items["ugcComment"]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Daniel . It worked. <% Comment c = new Comment(); %>
          
          <% c = HttpContext.Current.Items["ugcComment"] as Tridion.ContentDelivery.UGC.Web.Model.Comment; %>
          <% string emailAddress = c.User.EmailAddress; %>